# How to configure parameters with time stamp

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job ( parameterized build) I am using BUILD_ID as a parameter and I need to add time stamp for the every BUILD_ID.

How to add time-stamp to the parameter.

I need the BUILD_ID value like Test_Build_{time-stamp}.

Kindly help me

Comment: Test_Build is your job name? Are your working on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Test_Build is the build name let's assume it as build_num it's not a job name I am working on windows.

Comment: I think I have a solution with some bash commands for Linux. I can try to transpose that to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways to do this.

Probably your best bet is the [Dynamic Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in). On the plugin page, one of its main examples does almost exactly what you described.

The [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) allows you to run groovy code to generate your parameter value(s). Here's a screenshot of the plugin setup along with the groovy code:

[image]

The [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) allows you to insert environment variables from a properties file as a build step. Using this method you would basically have to have 2 build steps, one to create the properties file and another to read it.

Or using the [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), you can add a groovy script build step to modify the parameter value.

I'm sure there a number of other ways to accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Zen Timestamp plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) and use variable $BUILD_TIMESTAMP